# How do I toggle between buttons in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, apollo-client

I am trying to toggle between add and remove buttons in reactjs, it works fine until I reload the page, how do I make this change persist? as the button changes to "add to bin" from "remove from bin" on reload. Below is my code explaining this:

```
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import { UPDATE_IMAGE } from "./mutation";
import { useState } from 'react';
function NewBin(props) {
  
  
  const [uu, {err}] = useMutation(UPDATE_IMAGE);
  
  const [toggle,setToggle] = useState(false)
  
  const addBin = async () => {
    await uu({
      variables: {
        id: props.data.id,
        url: props.data.url,
        description: props.data.description,
        posterName: props.data.posterName,
        binned: true,
        userPosted: props.data.userPosted
        
      },
    });
  };

  const removeBin = async () => {
    await uu({
      variables: {
        id: props.data.id,
        url: props.data.url,
        description: props.data.description,
        posterName: props.data.posterName,
        binned: false,
        userPosted: props.data.userPosted
        
      },
    });
  };

  const comp1 = async () => {
    addBin();
    setToggle(true);
  }

  const comp2 = async () => {
    removeBin();
    setToggle(false);
  }
  
  
  return (
    <div className="Appp">
      {toggle ?  <button onClick={() => comp2()}>Remove from Bin</button>
      : <button onClick={() => comp1()}>Add to Bin</button>
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default NewBin;
```

NewBin's parent:

```
function UnsplashPosts() {
const classes = useStyles();
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(unsplashImages);
  
  if(error) {
    return <h1> error</h1>;
   }
   
   if(loading) {
    return <h1> loading</h1>;
   }
 

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.unsplashImages.map((data) => (
        
    <Card className={classes.card} variant='outlined'>
                <CardHeader className={classes.titleHead} title={data.posterName} />
                <CardMedia
                    className={classes.media}
                    component='img'
                    image={data.url}
                    title='image'
                />

                <CardContent>
                    <Typography variant='body2' color='textSecondary' component='span'>
                        <p>{data.description}</p>

                        <NewBin data={data}/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br></br>
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>  
      ))}
    
    </div>
  );
}
```

The binned field shows true or false if it is in the bin or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can persist the `toggle` state to localStorage, and initialize from localStorage.

- Use a state initializer function to read from localStorage and provide the initial state value.
- Use an `useEffect` hook to persist the updated `toggle` state to localStorage upon update.

Example:

```
function NewBin(props) {
  ...

  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(() => {
    // Load saved state from localStorage or provide fallback
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("toggle")) ?? false;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // Persist state to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("toggle", JSON.stringify(toggle));
  }, [toggle]);

  ...
```

Comment: Where do I add these? I put both in the function NewBin, I am  seeing Remove from Bin on all posts after adding to bin

Comment: @TomBrooke Yes, modify the code/logic in the `NewBin` component. Can you clarify what you mean by "I am seeing Remove from Bin on all posts after adding to bin"?

Comment: What I mean is do I make any changes to the existing code here? or just add these two to NewBIn

Comment: @TomBrooke I guess both. Change the `useState` code for the `toggle` state so it loads the initial state value, add the `useEffect` hook to persist it.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work, if I click on any of the images and add to bin, all of the posts get remove from bin, not sure why

Comment: @TomBrooke Sorry, but what does that have to do with your question regarding persisting the `toggle` state value so it is saved and reloaded when the page is refreshed? Perhaps there is more state elsewhere you need to persist so it's also reloaded when the app is remounted?